# Why is my Node.js server returning html code instead of a html webpage

Tags: node.js

I have built a simple server on Node.js. When I tried to load a simple HTML page (which was opened by Google Chrome successfully) by the server, `localhost8888` showed the HTML code instead of the page.

My code is as follows on Visual Studio Code IDE:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function send404response(response){
    response.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write('error 404: page not found');
    response.end();
}

function onRequest(request,response) {
    if(request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/'){
        response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        fs.createReadStream('./index.html').pipe(response);
    }else{
        send404response(response);
    }

}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("server is running ......")
```

My `index.html` page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang = 'en'>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> thenewboston </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        wow this site is awesome 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you set the [`Content-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header to `text/plain` the browser will display the content as text without interpreting the HTML.

Changing the content type to `text/html` should do the trick.

```
response.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
```

or

```
response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Content-Type header to text/html:

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Content-Type` needs to be `text/html`.

The correct code is...

```
response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
```

Instead of your line...

```
response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
```

Also, many people will run into a similar error where they do not specify the `DOCTYPE` in the HTML file. Once I had `DOCTYPE html` instead of `!DOCTYPE html` within the first tag, and this caused the server to respond with plain text as well.